# Trying to add websites to localstorage in chrome extension options page

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I want to be able to add websites to a chrome extension options page. So I have a text box with a "save" button and I want to be able to save multiple websites with the ability to edit or remove them later. Like this:

Enter URL: |***_*__*_*__*_*__**| |**_*save*_**|

Edit Remove - www.google.com
Edit Remove - www.msn.com
Edit Remove - www.yahoo.com

Once you enter a website and click save, it will add it to the list of websites already there. I've been trying to scavenge the internet to try to figure out how to accomplish this, but I just don't know enough about it to complete it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend `chrome.storage` instead of `localStorage`: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html

It's fantastic. You can even choose to store data online in your Google profile (100KB max). Otherwise offline (100MB max, I think).

API is super simple too:

```
chrome.storage.local.get('websites', function(items) {
  console.log('websites:', items.websites);
});
```

Unlike `localStorage`, it's async, so you'll be using callbacks. But it's lightning fast, so the UI won't notice.

What I'd do is not keep a virtual record of your storage, but keep it in HTML and read from/write to that as necessary:

- btnAdd adds a new LI to the list and then saves the list
- btnEdit fills the textfield and removes the LI from the list (no save) (saving via btnAdd)
- btnDelete removes the LI from the list and saves the list
- save = get items from list as array and save to storage
- init = load items from storage and fill list

http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/Zbpmx/

I'm assuming jQuery since it's popular. It's not necessary of course.

If you're having problems with this already, a Chrome extension will be insanely difficult.

Comment: This seems like a better solution, but like I said, I don't know enough about it to complete it. Hopefully you can elaborate a bit. I am basically storing a 1-dimensional array. I need to be able to add/edit/delete items in the array. How I picture it in my mind is I need to pull the current items (if there are any) into an array variable, use the .push() command to add items to the array, then save it back to the chrome storage with the added URL.

Comment: Here is what I have, but I'm getting an error:
`var URLarray = [];
chrome.storage.local.get('websites', function(items) {
  URLarray = items;
  URLarray.push(itemURL.value);
  chrome.storage.local.set({'websites': URLarray}, function() {
    alert('Settings saved');
  })
  console.log('websites:', items.websites);
});`

Comment: I wouldn't keep a virtual array/records. I'll update my answer with something semi-pseudo-code-ish.

Comment: Thank you for your help and time writing that code. But I'm not sure if this helps me accomplish my end goal. This is an options page and for my main reason for the extension, how does it read the options page if it's not in some type of storage?
Also, it works flawlessly in jsfiddle, but the add button doesn't work when I copy the code over to the extension. It just stays on the ...LOADING... text

Comment: You might be right about trying to build a Chrome extension - I might have to pass on it for now.